# Understanding Elasticsearch deployment in 2 server load balanced setup

Tags: elasticsearch, high-availability

We have a two server load balanced ASP.NET MVC application that we're look to add search to - we like the look of Elasticsearch!

I'd like to build a bit of resiliency in so am considering installing ES on both servers and have them work like a cluster (which seems straightforward enough according the docs).

But I really want my MVC app to talk to "the cluster" not to each specific ES node, so if an ES node fails, or a server fails the application is unaffected:

[image]

Do I need to refer to the cluster in a special way from my application or setup some kind of internal domain for it?

I don't want to refer to "localhost:9200" or a server specific IP in my application I presume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using the [Elasticsearch .NET Client NEST](http://nest.azurewebsites.com). This client has built in support for failover connections when accessing an Elasticsearch Cluster.

> If you want a failover client instead of passing a Uri pass an IConnectionPool see the Elasticsearch.Net documentation on cluster failover all of its implementations can also be used with NEST.

Comment: Never even considered there might be this capability - thanks Paige!